# Correct syntax insert an array into MongoDB with validation rules

Tags: arrays, mongodb, validation

I created a collection with validation rules using the following syntax:

```
>db.createCollection("CollName", {
   validator: {
      $jsonSchema:
{
    bsonType: "object",
    properties: {
        a1: {
            bsonType: "string",
        },
        a2:{
            bsonType: "string",
        },
        a3: {
            bsonType: "array",
            items: {
                bsonType: "object",
                  properties: {
                    b1: {
                        bsonType: "string",
                    },
                    b2: {
                        bsonType: "string",
                      }
                }
            }
        }

    }
}
}})
```

And I want to insert some documents into it. However, I am not able to find the correct syntax. I tried the following:

```
>  db.CollName.insert({
...  a1:"122234343",
...  a2: "name1",
...  a3: [b1: "aaa1111", b2: "bbb222"]
... })

2020-05-28T12:33:50.052+0200 E  QUERY    [js] uncaught exception: SyntaxError: missing ] after element list :
@(shell):4:8

>  db.CollName.insert({
...  a1:"122234343",
...  a2: "name1",
...  a3: ["aaa1111", "bbb222"]
... })

WriteResult({
    "nInserted" : 0,
    "writeError" : {
        "code" : 121,
        "errmsg" : "Document failed validation"
    }
})
```

How can I find the correct syntax?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
db.CollName.insert({
 "a1":"122234343",
 "a2": "name1",
 "a3": [{"b1": "aaa1111", "b2": "bbb222"}]
})
```

Comment: An explanation would be in order. E.g., what is the idea/gist? What did you change and why? What was the problem in the original? From [the Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion): *"...always explain why the solution you're presenting is appropriate and how it works"*. Please respond by [editing (changing) your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/62063188/edit), not here in comments (***without*** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today).